# PowerQuery: Replace only values that are a date

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to replace any cell that has a date in it with "null" so that I can fill values in PowerQuery.  I've used formula's that can can perform the replacement, but the non-date values that I want to remain as text are replaced with "Error".  Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work

```
#"RemoveDates" = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere",{{"Date", each try if Number.From(Date.From(_))>0 then null else _ otherwise _, type text}})
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like an absolute charm!

Comment: Ok wonderful, this was my first ever query so will make sure to do that from now on!  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   x = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Column1", (a)=> try Date.FromText(a) otherwise null  , type text}})
```